# Link to WinRT XAML code optimization

Tags: c#, regex, xaml

I need a method which will parse text to RichTextBlock-compatible XAML markup with clickable links.

Example:

Input:

```
"Hello, check new service for students! Check edusty.ru and http://edusty.ru/test?text1=abc&args=123 sites. Check edusty.ru/privacy.html to read privacy policy."
```

Output:

```
<Paragraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"  FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" >
     <Run Text="Hello, check new service for students! Check "/> 
     <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://edusty.ru">edusty.ru</Hyperlink> 
     <Run Text=" and "/>
     <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://edusty.ru/test?text1=abc&amp;args=123">http://edusty.ru/test?text1=abc&amp;args=123</Hyperlink> 
     <Run Text=" sites. Check "/>
     <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://edusty.ru/privacy.html">edusty.ru/privacy.html</Hyperlink>
     <Run Text=" to read privacy policy."></Run>
</Paragraph>
```

I wrote this method:

```
public static string ParseLinksToXaml(this string source)
        {
            var transformedText = Regex.Replace(source,
                @"((https?:\/\/)?(ftps?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/\S*)?)",
                @"""/> <Hyperlink NavigateUri=""$1"">$1</Hyperlink> <Run Text=""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            transformedText = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(transformedText);
            var matches = Regex.Matches(transformedText, @"&quot;\/&gt;\s&lt;Hyperlink NavigateUri=&quot;.*?&quot;&gt;|&lt;\/Hyperlink&gt;\s&lt;Run Text=&quot;");
            foreach (var match in matches)
                transformedText = transformedText.Replace(match.ToString(), WebUtility.HtmlDecode(match.ToString()));

            matches = Regex.Matches(transformedText, @"NavigateUri=\""(.*?)"">");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var link = match.Groups[1].ToString();
                link = link.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                link = link.Contains("://") ? link : "http://" + link;
                transformedText = transformedText.ReplaceFirst("\"" + match.Groups[1] + "\"", "\"" + link + "\"");
            }
            var xaml = @"<Paragraph xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" TextAlignment=""Left"" FontSize=""20""  FontWeight=""Normal"" FontStyle=""Normal"" FontStretch=""Normal"" >
                                    <Run Text=""" + transformedText + @"""></Run></Paragraph>";
            return xaml;
        }
```

It works, but the code really looks bad. Can anyone help rewrite/optimize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're concatenating strings inside a loop's body, `+`-concatenation should be ruled out; `transformedText` would be a `StringBuilder` instance, to which each iteration would `Append`.

However XAML is a subset of XML; as such, there is no reason to treat your output as purely strings: using the classes in the `System.Linq.Xml` namespace (otherwise known as "Linq-to-Xml"), you can rewrite this in a much more elegant and object-oriented way.

Extending `System.String` like this is a bit overkill, too. I'm not sure I'd like working in a code base where every single string out there has this `ParseLinksToXaml` extension method: that functionality is very specialized, and IMO deserves its own class where the client code is actually explicit about what's going on:

```
var parser = new StringLinksToXamlConverter();
var xaml = parser.ParseLinksToXaml(myString);
```

The string-building stuff going on under the hood should be an implementation detail - the returned value would be potentially much more useful to the client code if an `XDocument` was returned, leaving it up to the client code to query or output as a string.